# Accessing neural network weights and neuron activations

Tags: tensorflow, theano, deep-learning, caffe, keras

After training a network using Keras:

1. I want to access the final trained weights of the network in some order.
2. I want to know the neuron activation values for every input passed. For example, after training, if I pass `X` as my input to the network, I want to know the neuron activation values for that `X` for every neuron in the network.

Does Keras provide API access to these things? I want to do further analysis based on the neuron activation values.

**Update** : I know I can do this using Theano purely, but Theano requires more low-level coding. And, since Keras is built on top of Theano, I think there could be a way to do this?

If Keras can't do this, then among Tensorflow and Caffe , which can? Keras is the easiest to use, followed by Tensorflow/Caffe, but I don't know which of these provide the network access I need. The last option for me would be to drop down to Theano, but I think it'd be more time-consuming to build a deep CNN with Theano..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is covered in the [Keras FAQ](http://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer), you basically want to compute the activations for each layer, so you can do it with this code:

```
from keras import backend as K

#The layer number
n = 3 
# with a Sequential model
get_nth_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[n].output])
layer_output = get_nth_layer_output([X])[0]
```

Unfortunately you would need to compile and run a function for each layer, but this should be straightforward.

To get the weights, you can call [get_weights()](http://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/#about-keras-layers) on any layer.

```
nth_weights = model.layers[n].get_weights()
```

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax They are the activations, I have literally no idea what you are talking about, you should ask your own question with reproducible results if you have issues.